# Kendo TreeView with Hierarchial Data Source using ServerSide Wrappers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, treeview, kendo-ui, datasource

How can I create a HierarchialDataSource using MVC ServerSide wrappers and use it as the DataSource for a TreeView?

I have created a hierarchical structure that is returned from the controller as Json, but the TreeView only displays the top level nodes. Is there a property that needs to be set on the TreeView to indicate that the DataSource is heirarchial?

I saw several Client Side examples using JS and the kendo.data library, but I cannot find the server side equivalent assembly.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the properties of the model you're binding must match the HierarchicalDataSource:
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/hierarchicaldatasource

I'm using the treeview to display a menu structure, so here's my model:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int id
    {
        get { return this.Id; }
    }                

    public bool hasChildren { get; set; }
}
```

I explicitly had to implement the `id` and `hasChildren` properties with this exact casing (I'm populating the `hasCHildren` property based on the query before pushing the model to the view).

Not sure if it's the correct way of doing it (still stuggling to find the official info) but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your cshtml File:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
   .Name("trvReport")
   .DataTextField("Name")
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Read(read => read.Action("ReportType", "Read"))
      .Model(model =>
      {
        model.Id("Id");
        model.Field("Name", typeof(string));
        model.Children("Reports");
        model.HasChildren("HasReports");
      })
   )
)
```

Implement HasChildren in your Model like this:

```
public class ReportType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Report> Reports { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool HasReports { get { return Reports.Count() > 0; } }
}
```